# cv2.lbphfacerecognizer has no attribute 'load' 'predict'

Tags: python, load, predict

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
rec.load("recognizerr\\trainingData.yml")

id=0

fontface=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

while(True):

    ret,img=cam.read();
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if(id==1):
            id="Name"
        else:
            id="Unknown"    
        cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h),fontface,2,(255,0,0),3);
    cv2.imshow("Face",img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Facing the error in rec.load 
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\DELL PC\Downloads\faceDetec_YOUTUBE-20171021T212250Z-001\recognize\detector.py", line 7, in 
>       rec.load("recognizerr\trainingData.yml")
>   AttributeError: 'cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'load'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am using python 3.6.3 and openCv 3.3 and face the same problem. In openCV 3.3 has removed load() and save(). load() is replaced with read() and save() is replaced with write()

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
```

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV 3.3

**load() is replaced by read()**

**save() is replaced by write()**

Answer (score 1):

In openCV==3.x

```
load() is replaced with read() 
save() is replaced with write()
```