# How to save openCV classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pickle

I want to save a classifier that has been trained on multiple images to avoid the time it takes to re-train it every time I run the program. For sklearn's classifiers I was able to simply pickle them, using `pickle.load` but when I try doing the same I get following error:

> TypeError: can't pickle cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer objects

Heres the classifier itself:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# detecting face using haarcasade
face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, minNeighbors = 3)
# detecting region of interest and appending it to a separate matrix
for x, y, w, h in face:
     roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
     x_train.append(roi)
     y_train.append(label)
 clf.train(x_train, y_train)
```

Is there any way to save such classifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save such classifiers as a `.yml` file.

For example:

```
clf.save('trainingData.yml')
```

You can load the same using:

```
clf.load('trainingData.yml')
```

Comment: Saving does work, but when doing clf.load() I get error saying: object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: Apparently, the load() has been replaced with read() in newer versions of openCV.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I am using 3.4.1 and `load()` works for me

Comment: Strange, mine is 3.4.1 as well, but I googled the problem I was having with load() and I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873728/cv2-lbphfacerecognizer-has-no-attribute-load-predict. Oddly save() does work when this post is saying that it too had been replaced by write()